# Select mulitple files date from folder to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, openrowset

I am running following command

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(MAX);
DECLARE @path varchar(255);

SET @path = 'E:\BILL PRINT\RAVI\'
SET @sql = 'SELECT *  FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',
  ''Excel 12.0; Database='+@path+''+'*.xlsx;'+' HDR=YES; IMEX=1'', 
  ''SELECT * FROM [sheet1$]'')';

SELECT @sql 
EXEC (@sql)
```

But I get this error:

> OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'E:\BILL PRINT\RAVI*.xlsx'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'E:\BILL PRINT\RAVI*.xlsx' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.".
>
> Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".

Is that possible to import data from specified Excel files?

Please help me

Comment: yes it is possible, and i guess you should remove * char from the path.

Comment: no problem still exsist

Answer (score 0):

Run `SQL Server Management Studio` with `Run as administrator` and execute the script again.

And be sure your file path is correct.

Only one file you can read at the same time. That's why your script should be like this.

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(MAX);
DECLARE @path varchar(255);

SET @path = 'E:\BILL PRINT\RAVI\currency.xlsx'
SET @sql = 'SELECT *  FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',
  ''Excel 12.0; Database='+@path+''+';'+' HDR=YES; IMEX=1'', 
  ''SELECT * FROM [sheet1$]'')';

EXEC (@sql)
```

If you want to read all files in the folder. You can use this script. For get the file names `xp_cmdshell` used.

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(MAX);
DECLARE @path varchar(255);

DECLARE @fileNames TABLE (flname varchar(255))
INSERT @fileNames
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'dir E:\BILL PRINT\RAVI\*.xlsx /s/b ';

DECLARE fileCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT flname FROM @fileNames WHERE flname is not null

OPEN fileCursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM fileCursor   
INTO @path  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

    SET @sql = 'SELECT *  FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',
      ''Excel 12.0; Database='+@path+''+';'+' HDR=YES; IMEX=1'', 
      ''SELECT * FROM [sheet1$]'')';

    EXEC (@sql) 

    FETCH NEXT FROM fileCursor   
    INTO @path  
END
```

Comment: i tried  but no affect, my actual path is E:\BILL PRINT\RAVI\ and there are two files in this folder name is currency.xlsx and currency1.xlsx is there any problem with these files.

Comment: Only one file you can open at same time, try with `E:\BILL PRINT\RAVI\currency.xlsx`

Comment: seems like i run wrong command then i want to import all these files in a table  at same time from a folder. you have any suggestion how could i do this.